# PHP works with XAMMP locally, but not "live" online

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, localhost

I am taking a class in AJAX.  I have been testing the following files using an XAMPP portable server on my flash drive, and they work no problem locally.  When I post them to my class server they do not work and I get the error in my Chrome console: "uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'getelementsbytagname' of null" (see where noted below in code comment).

Why would these files work locally but then not live?  Purpose of the page is to input text to find customer names from an XML file, then populate the table with values from the XML file based on the letters typed in.  If typed text is deleted, table updates accordingly, and if no text is present, then there is no table.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

    function addToTable()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("input");
        var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType)
            {
                XMLHttpRequestObject.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
            }
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
        {
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", "hw8a.php?sid=" + Math.random() + "&qu=" + input.value);
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange =
            function()
            {
                if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)


                {
                    xmlDocument = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
                    if (xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("Data").length == 0)

// ERROR APPEARS HERE: "uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'getelementsbytagname' of null"
                    {
                        not_there();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        there(xmlDocument);
                    }
                }
            }
            XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }

    function there(documentElement)
    {
        if (input != "")
        {
            not_there();

            var nodeNames =  new Array("CustomerID", "FirstName", "LastName", "Address", "ZipCode", "Phone");

            var result = document.getElementById("result");

            customerCount = documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer").length;

            for(var i = 0; i < customerCount; i++)
            {
                var newRow = result.insertRow(i+1);
                customerNode = documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Customer")[i];

                for (var j = 0; j < nodeNames.length; j++)
                {
                    var col = newRow.insertCell(j);
                    col.innerHTML = customerNode.getElementsByTagName(nodeNames[j])[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function not_there()
    {
        var result = document.getElementById("result");

        while(result.rows.length > 1)
        {
        result.deleteRow(1);
        }
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 align="center">Choose Customer Information from the Database</h1>

<p align="center">Enter the last name of a customer here: <input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="addToTable();" /> and a table of customer data will appear below...</p>

<table align="center" cellspacing="5" id="result">

<tr><th>ID</th><th colspan="2">Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Zip</th><th>Phone</th></tr>

<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include "XMLParser.class";

header("Cache-Control: post-check=1,pre-check=2");

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';

echo '<Data>';

$xml = file_get_contents('Customer.xml');

$parser = new XMLParser($xml);

$parser->Parse();

$input = $_GET["qu"];

$found = false;

foreach( $parser->document->customer as $customer)
{
    if ($input == "")
    {
        echo "not_there()";
    }
    else if (stripos($customer->lastname[0]->tagData, $input) === 0) 
    {
        $found = true;
        echo '<Customer>';
        echo '<CustomerID>' . $customer->customerid[0]->tagData . '</CustomerID>';
        echo '<FirstName>' . $customer->firstname[0]->tagData . '</FirstName>';
        echo '<LastName>' . $customer->lastname[0]->tagData . '</LastName>';
        echo '<Address>' . $customer->address[0]->tagData . '</Address>';
        echo '<ZipCode>' . $customer->zipcode[0]->tagData . '</ZipCode>';
        echo '<Phone>' . $customer->phone[0]->tagData . '</Phone>';
        echo '</Customer>';
    }
}

echo '</Data>';

?>
```

Sample of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
        <Phone>(999) 555-1111</Phone>
        <FirstName>Something</FirstName>
        <LastName>Something</LastName>
        <Address>1234 Something Street</Address>
        <ZipCode>99999</ZipCode>
    </Customer>
        . . .
</Data>
```

Comment: `console.log(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML)` - make sure it's returning your XML and not an error or something.

Comment: chris is right. you may have error_reporting disabled on your local machine

Comment: Error reporting is enabled.  Again, this is working locally, and no errors are being generated, but it just won't work when posted live and the error noted in the code shows up only when running live.

Comment: That code has _some_ fatal error after `<Data>`, I suspect it can't find the `XMLParser` class. Always _require_ files you _need_. And most likely: case-insensitive versus case-sensitive platform, check the case of your `XMLParser.class` string versus your _actual_ filename.

Comment: Found the "fatal" error - in my PHP file, in the "else if" statement, it was the "stripos" function that was not working.  "strpos" works, but that is case-sensitive.  Don't know why "stripos" doesn't work, because I want it to be case-INsensitive.  Any ideas?

Comment: Replaced "stripos" function with this "else if (preg_match ("/^" . $input . ".*$/i", $customer->lastname[0]->tagData) >= 1)" and now works fine.  Thanks to everyone who responded and steered me in the right direction.